# Retrieve SMS Send Time and Receive Time Android

Tags: java, android, sms

so I want to retrieve the time send and time receive of the SMS. When we send an SMS, the receiver will receive it immediately. But, sometimes there's provider or network error so the receiver will receive it in the time when their provider/network is good. What I want to do is to differentiate between the time send (when the sender send it) and time receive (when the receiver receive it). Is there any way to do it?

This is my code.

```
    public ArrayList<String> getSMS(){
    ArrayList<String> sms = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

    while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
        String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
        String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
        String date = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
        long milliSeconds = Long.parseLong(date);
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy");
        DateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aaa");
        DateFormat timeFormatterTwo = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
        String finalDateString = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
        timeOne = timeFormatter.format(calendar.getTime());
        timeTwo = timeFormatterTwo.format(calendar.getTime());
        isTime = false;
        titleArrays.add(new ItemProperty("From: "+address, finalDateString, timeOne, body));
    }

    if (cur != null) {
        cur.close();
    }
    return sms;
}
```

If you guys know what I should do, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: For which messages are you wanting this? Ones the user is sending? Ones that they're receiving? All of them? In any case, the answer is likely going to be: Not really, not with any real accuracy, anyway. For sent messages, that would require a delivery report. Not all carriers offer delivery reports, and the time of receipt for those is not recorded in the Provider anyway, so you would only be able to do that for messages that your app is sending directly. Even then, though, the meaning of "delivered" varies, and doesn't necessarily mean the message has arrived at the device yet.

Comment: For received messages, there is the `date` column for the (approximate) time arrived at the device, and there is also the `date_sent` column, but that is actually the Service Center Time Stamp, not the time it left the sender's device. You could do better with your app sending specially crafted messages to itself on another device, but for any given arbitrary message, it's not gonna be great.